# Interpreting EXIF GPSYaw values

Tags: canon, exiftool, gps

I have been extracting the geographic information from a number of photographs. This spatial information is stored in the photograph's exif data.

Part of the data I am extracting is the GPSRoll, GPSPitch and GPSYaw.

I am plotting these locations on a Leaflet map and was looking to impart some additional information onto the map using symbology.

I am trying to interpret the GPSYaw values into a direction attribute I can use to either generate a line or change the style of the point to some predetermined symbol. The question I have relates to how do I interpret the values coming out of the GPSYaw field of the exif data.

The values lie within a range of 0 to 180 and 0 to -180. Am I correct in assuming that the postive value relate to a direction relative to north from North, East and South and the negative values are North, West and South?

Or is this too simplistic and the GPSYaw relates to something completely different, or is somehow a combination of the pitch and roll values?

Comment: In math, positive angles are Count-clockwise so there is a chance that 0 to +180 is actually North-West-South. Why don't you take a few shots with a known orientation? Otherwise, since you know the time and place of a photo, you can use Google earth to visit the location and deduce the orientation of the camera (easier in photos with city landscapes).

Comment: Thank you for that. I will see what I can determine from the imagery. Unfortunately I don’t have access to the camera to test and the photos are in a rural location of electrical poles taken from the air. So identifying landmarks is rough. But I will still give it a go. Thank you.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about using a camera and the resulting images as data collection points to create maps, not to produce photographs for the sake of photographs as the end result.

Comment: I’d vote to close too if this breaks the Photography SE rules. . Was asked to post here by the GIS SE. They not too sure what to do with it either. I figured it was photography related as it is information pertaining to photographs.